# Properties of functional integration

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics

this question comes from theoretical Physics, the issue being the so called Path Integral. The measure of this thing is something written as

$[d\phi]=\prod_x d\phi(x)$

And this should be the limit of something defined by working on a discrete lattice of points over the integration domain: this lattice becomes finer and finer and you get some formal definition of the above formula.

Now, the question. I assume that the following equation does NOT hold (by considering the above mentioned limiting procedure), where $a$ is just some constant number:

$[d(a\phi)]= a[d\phi]$

Correct? I imagine to get something that goes like $a^N$, where $N$ is the number of points in each finite lattice discretization.

Comment: It is correct that $[d(a\phi)]=a[d\phi]$ does not hold (this would correspond to a one-dimensional integral). You should beware that the object $[d\phi]$ should not be interpreted as a measure, rather an object such as $e^{-h(\phi)}[d\phi]$ would correspond to a measure.

Comment: Thanks. Makes perfect sense.